# How can I use two conditions for my `IF` block?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a problem to create double conditions with If, so this is what I have for hiding a line:

```
If Target.Address = "$D$35" Then
    If (Target.Value = "No") Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("37:40").Rows.Hidden = False
    End If
    If (Target.Value = "Yes") Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("37:40").Rows.Hidden = True
    End If
End If
```

Now, I want to add another condition for this formula, let's say that that cell `$D$35` need to be *"No"* and Cell `$D$36` need to be *"done"* in order for the Hide function to work.

How do I insert this to my existing formula ?

Comment: Have you considered `And`?!

Comment: If you expect different anwsers you can also use `Select case`.

Comment: Guys, I am very new to this. this code was written by my friend and I am trying to expand it. the issue is that the condition need to be on 2 Cells(each cell with one condition) and not 1 Cell with two conditions. That's my problem.

Comment: @user2802195 Then we need more information ... and maybe you should first check some basic notions about VBA for excel (how to acces cells, stuff like that) because there is nothing difficult with what you try to achieve. In your case you just need an other cell var (like `Target`) or use `Range()`, `Cells()` etc ...

Comment: Well basically I need 1 Cell to be equal to "X" and the second Cell = "Y" , only when I have these two Cells in this specific condition I wanna hide or un-hide few lines.

Comment: @user2802195 I added an example to my answer, check out to see if this helps ...

Answer (score 1):

**1.** You can use `And` for multiple conditions *(cf @jonrsharpe comment)*. 
Actually take a look at other logical operators like `Or` etc ... [Logical and Bitwise Operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz3k228a.aspx)

**2.** Why don't you use `If\ElseIf\Else` ? 
It's quite obvious that if `Target.Value = "No"` is *true* you do not have to test if `Target.Value = "Yes"` ...

So just do something like that:

```
If cond1 And cond2 Then
    ' Some code
ElseIf cond3 And cond4 Then '<--editted
    ' Some code
Else
    ' Some code
End If
```

### Example:

Let's say you want to do a condition on the values of cell `D35` ($D$35) and `D36` you can just do:

```
If Range("D35")= "No" And Range("D36")= "No" Then
    ActiveSheet.Range("37:40").Rows.Hidden = False
ElseIf Range("D35")= "Yes" And Range("D36")= "done" Then
    ActiveSheet.Range("37:40").Rows.Hidden = True
End If
```

Instead of

```
If Target.Address = "$D$35" Then
    If (Target.Value = "No") Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("37:40").Rows.Hidden = False
    End If
    If (Target.Value = "Yes") Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("37:40").Rows.Hidden = True
    End If
End If
```

**Note 1:** this assumes you are working on the right sheet

**Note 2:** this isn't especially the best way to do ...

Comment: Hi, this code was written by my friend and I am trying to expand it. the issue is that the condition need to be on 2 Cells(each cell with one condition) and not 1 Cell with two conditions. That's my problem.

Answer (score 0):

First, it's not a formula, it's a subroutine. Second, you don't have to have multiple `IF` blocks. Just one should suffice.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D35:D36")) Is Nothing Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("37:40").Rows.Hidden = (Range("D35").Value = "No" And Range("D36").Value = "Done")
    End If

End Sub
```

A little explanation is in order:

1. `If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D35:D36")) Is Nothing` returns `TRUE` if the change is detected in either `D35` or `D36`. If you want the condition to check in non-contiguous ranges, use `Union` on the ranges you want to check.
2. `(Range("D35").Value = "No" And Range("D36").Value = "Done")` evaluates to `TRUE` if both conditions are met, `FALSE` if else. We then use this as the boolean trigger for the `Hidden` property of the given range.

Hope this helps.